# How to convert vector to string of a particular type

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector in c++ of the form (1,2,3). I want this vector to be a string "1->2->3". Can anyone help me how can I convert the vector to this string?

I have tried this code but the constraint is that I can't use `itoa()` method or `to_str`.

```
string stringify(vector<int> v)
{
    string s = "";
    for(int i=0;i<v.size()-1;i++){
        s = itoa(v[i]);
        s = s + "->"
    }
    s = s+v[i];
    cout<<s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. And then we'll help if you have some specified issues.

Comment: I converted the digits to string by using itoa() function and then appended "->" after each of them but it doesn't work. Any other way will be appreciated because my way has too much hassle.

Comment: You need to post your code and output please.

Comment: if u can use c++11, there is an example on cppreference itself using : 
[std::accumulate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)
or you cud take reference from that code to write your own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [std::stringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream):

```
string stringify(const vector<int>& v)
{
    stringstream ss;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        if (i != 0) ss << "->";
        ss << v[i];
    }

    return ss.str();
}
```

[LIVE](http://rextester.com/JPO75407)

BTW1: You might change the parameter type from passing by value to passing by reference, to avoid the copy of the `vector`.
BTW2: You might make `stringify` a template function which could be used generically. e.g.

```
template <typename T>
string stringify(const vector<T>& v)
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it in c, look if it is useful to you:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #define SIZE 2

    void stringify(char*);

    int main()
    {
        char v = {1,2,3};
        stringify(v);

        printf("\n\n");
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    void stringify(char v[])
    {
        char s[20]=" ";
        char aux[20] = "";

        for(int i=0;i <= SIZE;i++)
        {
            if(i < SIZE)
                sprintf(s, "v[%d] -> ", &v[i]);
            else
                sprintf(s, "v[%d]", &v[i]);

            printf("", strcat(aux,s));


        }
        printf("\n%s", aux);
    }
```

Now the array aux contains all the  output with format.

output:

[image]